# How to restart MAAS

Tags: maas

I can't work out how to restart MAAS, can anyone help? There's nothing in /etc/init.d that I can see.

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 5):

If MAAS was installed via snap, use `sudo snap restart maas.supervisor`

Answer (score 3):

Look inside /etc/init for the conf files instead. You'll find some of the MaaS support services.
In addition to restarting the apache server (for the region site) MaaS has quite a bunch, depending on what you need restarted.

There's dhcp.

```
sudo service maas-dhcpd restart
```

The cluster daemon,which is essentially the provision manager including twisted and TFTP.

```
sudo service maas-clusterd restart
```

The bind9/named service which is vanilla but has maas configs & zones inside.

```
sudo service bind9 restart
```

Answer (score 3):

As a hack, this is what I usually do:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller
```

Do NOT change anything. Simply press ENTER. It would stop some of the processes you may need restarted. After the ENTER, it would start them back up. +1 for the answer from lanous.

Comment: What's the equivalent for snap installations?

Answer (score 1):

MAAS is run by your webserver, try `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. If you use another webserver, you need to restart that.

Answer (score 1):

#!/bin/bash

```
for service in `ls -1 /lib/systemd/system/maas-*.service`
do
   maas_srv=`basename $service`
   systemctl restart $maas_srv
done
```

Comment: Please, an explanation can go a long way to help.